# Entity Framework Retrieve a subset of data from the

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a working EF system with foreign keys and so on that enables me to pull back all my customer data for a shop or chain of shops.

I obtain the data by using the following code.

```
var foo = from s in context.Shops
        where (s.ShopId == shopId)
        select s;
```

Shop has a navigation property defined as;

```
 [ForeignKey("ShopId")] 
 public virtual ICollection<CustomerOrder> CustomerOrders { get; set; }
```

Amongst other things, CustomerOrder contains a status and a Completed Date.

So currently in my code I have the following that returns all the Completed Orders (status 7) that have been completed since a particular date.

```
[NotMapped]
public virtual List<CustomerOrder> TotalCompletedCustomerOrders(DateTime dt)
{
    return (from co in CustomerOrders where co.Status == 7 && co.CompletedDate > dt select co).ToList();            
}
```

Is this the most efficient way for me to retrieve my data? (I appreciate that Customer orders are not retrieved until the collection is enumerated, but even then the system has to process potentially many thousand records to find those completed after the date. 
is it possible or desirable to include the status and / or date in the original query?

I have tried several variations on the following, but none work.

```
where (d.ParentBusinessId == parentId && (d.CustomerOrders.Select(co => co.Status == 7)))
```

Or am I over engineering this process? (In theory, I'd like the method that selects the data from the database to take in a status and optional date, so when I pass my data to the web page, all it needs to do is present it)

Comment: if you are unsure, give this ago http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof, this tool will also provide some assistance on what you are doing wrong (I.e. select n+1 etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"the system" in this case is the sql server, and that's its job to select a set of data from a much larger set.  You do have to pay attention to the query execution plan if it's not performing well, but the idea of being concerned that a SQL Server has to process a subset of records from a much larger set is the whole point of having a SQL server.  It's very efficient at doing this.

Your original query is optimized to do a subselect in most cases, so just let EF and the SQL Server do its job, and if you have a performance problem, then deal with it.

Comment: No worries. I'll leave it all as it is then unless we start to get issues with it. Thanks